# Magento product details page not loading after search result

Tags: magento

In my magento website, whenever i am trying to view the product details page from search result (means product list is generated from the search query) its not loading the product details page properly. After the breadcrumbs its not displaying anything.The sample url is given below.

https://www.example.com/index.php/test.html

And the breadcrumbs is displaying like Home/test.html

If I go the category page and view the same particular product then it shows perfectly with below url.

https://www.example.com/index.php/category1/test.html  and breadcrumbs looks like Home/category1/test.html.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually problem was on my `catalog/product/view.phtml` page. I have a magento store with 30k products and I have used a theme which have functionality to displaying Pre/Next product in details page for this details page was taking lot of time to execute. I have just removed the pre/next functionality from `catalog/product/view.phtml` page and it works fine.I have also truncated the core_url_rewrite table and Reindex Catalog URL Rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

Truncate the url_rewrite table.
Delete all files from var/locks.
Reindex and i think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have done as per your suggestion but problem is not solved.

Comment: set use category path for product urls to No in admin panel.

Comment: I have found one error as well, it shows "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted".